# How to put chapter number after chapter title in thesis documentclass?

Tags: thesis

Why chapter title in thesis documentclass  positioned below chapter number? I mean I need to place both of chapter title and chapter number in one line. 
[image]

Comment: Something seems to be amiss with your chapter header in terms of the spacing before the number. Did you change something already in that regard? Are you using a special `\documentclass`? Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the current layout?

Comment: Can you give us an MWE, so that we can see, what packages you are using and what attempts you have tried? one nice way to format the titles of sections, chapters and so on is the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, using the titlesec package with the explicit option:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]{\filcenter\color{blue}\normalfont\bfseries\huge\boldmath}{}{0ex}{#1\quad\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\thechapter}%



\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

Once upon a time, a long while ago, there were four little people whose names were Violet, Slingsby, Guy and Lionel,  and they all thought they should like to see the world. So they bought a large boat to sail quite round the world by sea, and then they were to come back on the other side by land. The boat was painted blue with green spots, and the sail was yellow with red stripes; and when they set off, they only took a small Cat to steer and look after the boat, besides an elderly Quangle-Wangle, who had to cook dinner and make the tea; for which purposes they took a large kettle.

\end{document}
```

[image: Result:]

Of course, you can change \filcenter to \filleft or filright